# jquery + check for div with class & custom data attribute

Tags: jquery, html

I need to be able to check if there is a div with class='active' and with a custom attribute data-popup='true' - eg: second one below.

[image]

How can I check if a div with these 2 characteristics exists?

I know its not correct but I have been playing with the following code:

```
 if($('div#mainContainer div.active div[data-unique='+urlUnique+']').length > 0) {
```

In the long run there will be many DIV's so it needs to find if one with this class and data attribute exists.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the selector you want:

```
$('#mainContainer div.active[data-popup=true]');
```